# How to enable CDR on AsteriskNow 1.5

Tags: asterisk

I have upgraded PBX to `Asterisk 1.6.2.7` and now CDR files are not created. It looks that such logging is disabled:

```
Connected to Asterisk 1.6.2.7 currently running on pbx2 (pid = 5824)
Verbosity is at least 3
pbx2*CLI> cdr show status
pbx2*CLI>
Call Detail Record (CDR) settings
----------------------------------
    Logging:                    Disabled
    Mode:                       Simple
```

Asterisk shows that CDR modules are loaded:

```
pbx2*CLI> module show like cd
Module                         Description                              Use Count
cdr_manager.so                 Asterisk Manager Interface CDR Backend   0
cdr_csv.so                     Comma Separated Values CDR Backend       0
app_cdr.so                     Tell Asterisk to not maintain a CDR for  0
app_forkcdr.so                 Fork The CDR into 2 separate entities    0
func_cdr.so                    Call Detail Record (CDR) dialplan functi 0
cdr_custom.so                  Customizable Comma Separated Values CDR  0
6 modules loaded
```

How to enable creating CDR csv files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was bug in `Asterisk Now`. It needed `/etc/asterisk/cdr.conf` which was absent.

Answer (score 1):

We had to follow some more steps.

We needed some CDR logging ASAP and our AsteriskNOW server did not have modules for MySQL CDR logging. We would not install new packages in a running, highly requested production server, so we relied on CSV logging.

To enable it is easy. First, we edit `/etc/asterisk/cdr.conf` (if it does not exist, we create it) adding a `[csv]` section. We added some more configuration on it as below, but apparently the important thing is to create the section.

```
[csv]
usegmtime=yes    
loguniqueid=yes  
loguserfield=yes 
accountlogs=yes
```

Then, we edited `/etc/asterisk/modules.conf` for loading the `cdr_csv.so` module:

```
; Loading cdr
load => cdr_csv.so
```

For enabling the logging immediately without restarting Asterisk, we called `asterisk -vvvr` and loaded the module:

```
voip*CLI> module load cdr_csv.so
```

Now every call is logged in `/var/log/asterisk/cdr-csv/Master.csv`.

It took us some time to get it working. [This page](http://www.asterisk.org/doxygen/trunk/Config_cdr.html) proved itself as a useful reference.